# Fastest way to append nonzero numpy array elements to list

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I want to add all nonzero elements from a `numpy` array `arr` to a list `out_list`. Previous research suggests that for numpy arrays, using `np.nonzero` is most efficient. (My own benchmark below actually suggests it can be slightly improved using `np.delete`).

However, in my case I want my output to be a list, because I am combining many arrays for which I don't know the number of nonzero elements (so I can't effectively preallocate a numpy array for them). Hence, I was wondering whether there are some synergies that can be exploited to speed up the process. While my naive list comprehension approach is much slower than the pure numpy approach, I got some promising results combining list comprehension with `numba`.

Here's what I found so far:

```
import numpy as np

n = 60_000  # size of array
nz = 0.3  # fraction of zero elements

arr = (np.random.random_sample(n) - nz).clip(min=0)

# method 1
def add_to_list1(arr, out):
    out.extend(list(arr[np.nonzero(arr)]))

# method 2
def add_to_list2(arr, out):
    out.extend(list(np.delete(arr, arr == 0)))

# method 3
def add_to_list3(arr, out):
    out += [x for x in arr if x != 0]

# method 4 (not sure how to get numba to accept an empty list as argument)
@njit
def add_to_list4(arr):
    return [x for x in arr if x != 0]

out_list = []
%timeit add_to_list1(arr, out_list)

out_list = []
%timeit add_to_list2(arr, out_list)

out_list = []
%timeit add_to_list3(arr, out_list)

_ = add_to_list4(arr)  # call once to compile
out_list = []
%timeit out_list.extend(add_to_list4(arr))
```

Yielding the following results:

```
2.51 ms ± 137 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
2.19 ms ± 133 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
15.6 ms ± 183 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
1.63 ms ± 158 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Not surprisingly, `numba` outperforms all other methods. Among the rest, method 2 (using `np.delete`) is the best. Am I missing any obvious alternative that exploits the fact that I am converting to a list afterwards? Can you think of anything to further speed up the process?

### Edit 1:

Performance of `.tolist()`:

```
# method 5
def add_to_list5(arr, out):
    out += arr[arr != 0].tolist()

# method 6
def add_to_list6(arr, out):
    out += np.delete(arr, arr == 0).tolist()

# method 7
def add_to_list7(arr, out):
    out += arr[arr.astype(bool)].tolist()
```

Timings are on par with `numba`:

```
1.62 ms ± 118 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
1.65 ms ± 104 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each
1.78 ms ± 119 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

### Edit 2:

Here's some benchmarking using Mad Physicist's suggestion to use `np.concatenate` to construct a `numpy` array instead.

```
# construct numpy array using np.concatenate
out_list = []
t = time.perf_counter()
for i in range(100):
    out_list.append(arr[arr != 0])
result = np.concatenate(out_list)
print(f"Time elapsed: {time.perf_counter() - t:.4f}s")

# compare with best list-based method
out_list = []
t = time.perf_counter()
for i in range(100):
    out_list += arr[arr != 0].tolist()
print(f"Time elapsed: {time.perf_counter() - t:.4f}s")
```

Concatenating `numpy` arrays yields indeed another significant speed-up, although it is not directly comparable since the output is a `numpy` array instead of a list. So it will depend on the precise use what will be best.

```
Time elapsed: 0.0400s
Time elapsed: 0.1430s
```

### TLDR;

1/ using `arr[arr != 0]` is the fastest of all the indexing options

2/ using `.tolist()` instead of `list(.)` speeds up things by a factor 1.3 - 1.5

3/ with the gains of 1/ and 2/ combined, the speed is on par with `numba`

4/ if having a `numpy` array instead of a `list` is acceptable, then using `np.concatenate` yields another gain in speed by a factor of ~3.5 compared to the best alternative

Comment: Try substituting `...tolist()` for `list(...)`

Comment: Agreed with @hpaulj: `(...).tolist()` is about 2.5x times faster than `list(...)`. Also, there is a problem with your timing: using `%timeit out_list.extend(...)` makes the `out_list` longer and longer for each `timeit` loop. You'll end up doing a ton of memalloc. Example: `out_list = []; %timeit out_list.extend([1,2,3]); len(out_list)` makes a 243_333_333 long list on my system.

Comment: I tried to `.tolist()` and found indeed a significant gain in speed.

Comment: @Pierre_D I realize that `out_list` is growing longer and longer, but this was intentional, because it mirrors my actual use case. Or is there a problem with benchmarking this way that I don't see?

Comment: yes, there is a problem as `timeit` adjusts the number of loops based on the ongoing time, so that affects your results. Even in the example your provide, the 4th method is used for 1000 loops and 7 runs, 10 times more than the others. I would rather control explicitly how many arrays are added, as part of the test, like in the example at the end of my answer.

Comment: @Pierre_D Good point about the number of loops adjusting! So this implicitly penalizes faster approaches (given that presumably later iterations are slower due to the size of the list growing)

Comment: my overall summary: use `.tolist()`, not `list(.)`; use `arr[arr != 0]`, not `arr[np.nonzero(arr)]`; and if you can accept a `numpy` array as result instead of a list, then `np.concatenate([a[a != 0] for a in arrays])` is 6x faster. Oh, and using `a[a.astype(bool)]` is more than 2x slower compared to `a[a != 0]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of extending a list by all of the elements of a new array, append the array itself. This will make for much fewer and smaller reallocations. You can also pre-allocate a list of `None`s up-front or even use an object array, if you have an upper bound on the number of arrays you will process.

When you're done, call `np.concatenate` on the list.

So instead of this:

```
L = []
for i in range(10):
    arr = (np.random.random_sample(n) - nz).clip(min=0)
    L.extend(arr[np.nonzero(arr)])
result = np.array(L)
```

Try this:

```
L = []
for i in range(10):
    arr = (np.random.random_sample(n) - nz).clip(min=0)
    L.append(arr[np.nonzero(arr)])
result = np.concatenate(L)
```

Since you're keeping arrays around, the final concatenation will be a series of buffer copies (which is fast), rather than a bunch of python-to numpy type conversions (which won't be). The exact method you choose for deletion is of course still up to the result of your benchmark.

Also, here's another method to add to your benchmark:

```
def add_to_list5(arr, out):
    out.extend(list(arr[arr.astype(bool)]))
```

I don't expect this to be overwhelmingly fast, but it's interesting to see how masking stacks up next to indexing.

Comment: Great suggestion! I added both the `np.concatenate` and the `bool`-based indexing to my benchmarks in the OP. I will have to test how having the result in a `numpy` array instead of a list will affect the speed of my later code, but if its similar that's a speed up by a factor of 3.5!

Answer (score 3):

I submit that the method of choice, if you are indeed looking for a `list` output, is:

```py
def f(arr, out_list):
    out_list += arr[arr != 0].tolist()
```

It seems to beat all the other methods mentioned so far in the OP's question or in other responses (at the time of this writing).

If, however, you are looking for a result as a `numpy` array, then following @MadPhysicist's version (slightly modified to use `arr[arr != 0]` instead of using `np.nonzero()`) is almost 6x faster, see at the end of this post.

Side note: I would *avoid* using `%timeit out_list.extend(some_list)`: it keeps adding to `out_list` during the many loops of `timeit`. Example:

```py
out_list = []
%timeit out_list.extend([1,2,3])
```

and now:

```py
>>> len(out_list)
243333333  # yikes
```

**Timings**

On 60K items on my machine, I see:

```py
out_list = []

a = %timeit -o out_list + arr[arr != 0].tolist()
b = %timeit -o out_list + arr[np.nonzero(arr)].tolist()
c = %timeit -o out_list + list(arr[np.nonzero(arr)])
```

Yields:

```
1.23 ms ± 10.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
1.53 ms ± 2.53 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
4.29 ms ± 3.02 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

And:

```py
>>> c.average / a.average
3.476

>>> b.average / a.average
1.244
```

**For a `numpy` array result instead**

Following @MadPhysicist, you can get some extra boost by *not* turning the arrays into lists, but using `np.concatenate()` instead:

```py
def all_nonzero(arr_iter):
    """return non zero elements of all arrays as a np.array"""
    return np.concatenate([a[a != 0] for a in arr_iter])

def all_nonzero_list(arr_iter):
    """return non zero elements of all arrays as a list"""
    out_list = []
    for a in arr_iter:
        out_list += a[a != 0].tolist()
    return out_list
```

```py
from itertools import repeat

ta = %timeit -o all_nonzero(repeat(arr, 100))
tl = %timeit -o all_nonzero_list(repeat(arr, 100))
```

Yields:

```
39.7 ms ± 107 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
227 ms ± 680 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

and

```py
>>> tl.average / ta.average
5.75
```

Comment: Lots of good information in this answer! I am accepting Mad Physicist's answer, because in my specific case the np.concatenation clearly outperforms all other options. But thanks for the great answer and testing

Comment: Also, could you please benchmark `!=0` against `.astype(bool)`. I suspect the latter may have marginally less overhead to get to the same inner loop, but am on mobile and can't really confirm anything.

Comment: @Pierre D, I played around with your benchmark method at the end of your answer and found that for `all_nonzero_list` I can speed things up by a factor of 1.6 by using list comprehension instead of looping: `return [a[a != 0].tolist() for a in arr_iter]`

Comment: @MadPhysicist using PierreD's benchmarking method at the end of his answer, I am seeing `.astype(bool)` to be slightly slower than `!= 0` (142ms vs 120ms when using list comprehension as per my previous comment). This is also consistent with what I got in edit 1 to my OP using my original benchmarking method

Comment: one more thing: when increasing the number of nonzero elements, the relative difference between the different methods gets smaller. But according to my testing, the ordering stays the same

Comment: @Bob. That makes sense. Both almost certainly redirect to the same internal loop, so you're seeing a difference in the overhead, which is going to be pretty much a constant.